# Issue getting the list of followers using Instagram API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am working on Instagram API and try to fetch list of followers but API return
error. Please suggest me possible reason for this issue

**URL:** https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=*MY_ACCESS_TOKEN*

```
{
"meta": {
"code": 400,
"error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException",
"error_message": "This request requires scope=follower_list, but this access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your application with scope=follower_list to be granted this permissions."
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message says it all: you need to re-authorize with scope=follower_list to obtain the permissions.

Probably something like: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXX&redirect_uri=YYYYY&scope=basic+follower_list

Comment: i re-authorize with this api but they return this error
{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "You must include a valid client_id, response_type, and redirect_uri parameters"}

Comment: I took some time to login to instagram developer and try to create a new Client, but there it says: "Starting 10/1/2017, all permissions other than the basic permission will be unavailable to submit for or obtain." So I think you're out of luck. Also found this thread on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313375/instagram-bans-access-to-its-api

Comment: yours mean that according to new rules of instagram now we can not get the list of follower using instagram api ?

Comment: That is what I guess yeah. But don't do anything with the Instagram API nor do I work for them, so it's all assumptions.